# Where should I add the API key in ORS Tools?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, api, isochrone

I want to make an isochrone for my halte and station points. But I have to configure [ORS Tools](https://github.com/GIScience/orstools-qgis-plugin) with my API key. The problem is, I can't find any configuration button in my ORS Tools plugin.

How should I add my API key to my ORS Tools?

My QGIS view:

[image: QGIS screenshot]

Comment: What is a "halte point"?

Comment: My bad...what I mean is bus stop point. I'm sorry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open ORS Tool window. Click Settings button.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Check the *'Provider Settings'* where an API Key can be given

[image: window]

*Environment:* QGIS 3.18 on Windows 10