# QGIS OpenRouteService plugin: using OpenRouteService run in Docker rather than the ORS main API

Tags: qgis, network, docker

So I am trying use the OpenRouteService plugin in QGIS to calculate the drive times and distances between two sets of points. However the size of my file exceeds the allowed data usage of the OpenRouteService API. When I went on to OpenRouteService's forum another user recommended that I run an instance of OpenRouteService in Docker, as there are no limits on data usage with this approach. I was curious if anyone know if it is possible to link an instance in Docker back to QGIS as I am far more familiar with the QGIS interface than Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to link QGIS to Docker. You need the 'Open Route Service plugin' to use the API exposed by the dedicated instance you deploy with Docker.

'Open Route Service plugin' allows you to select the ORS provider (other than the default ORS API), so it will be straightforward on that front.

This is described in their [documentation](https://heigit.org/new-openrouteservice-qgis-plugin/)

[image]

What you have to do is follow the instructions to run the ORS service in a Docker instance, which will expose an URL to call the ORS API.

In case of a deployment on your local machine it will look like `localhost:8080/ors/`, or any other port than 8080 that you might specify on the Docker setup.

Comment: Ref.: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397837/where-should-i-add-the-api-key-in-ors-tools

Comment: So have done everything mentioned here but I keep getting the error message “Route from DI_531 to DI_531 caused a ApiError:                                                                    
404 ({“error”:{“code”:2010,“message”:“Could not find routable point within a radius of 350.0 meters of specified coordinate 0: -122.6305540 47.5934740.”},“info”:{“engine”:{“version”:“6.8.0”,“build_date”:“2023-01-07T20:56:46Z”},“timestamp”:1673140948884}})”. It appears as though the latitude and longitude values are getting mixed up.

Comment: The good thing is that you have an ORS instance runnin locally now . I think one good next step might be the ORS forum : https://ask.openrouteservice.org/c/sdks/10. In the ORS getting started there is probably a sample query to test from (without going through the plugin & qgis geometries)?